# Python unique grouping people task

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

My task is to generate all posible way to group given number of people from given number of total people. For example, if there are 4 guys at total, for groups that contain 2 guys, I have to get array like this:

```
ResultArr = {0: [1,2], 1:[1,3], 2:[1,4], 3:[2,3], 4:[2,4], 5:[3,4]}
```

I have this code:

```
elNum = 3 #Number of guys in one group
elLimit = 5 #Number of all guys

CheckArr = [1] * elNum
ResultArr = {}
ResultArr[0] = [-1] * elNum
goodCheckArr = [1] * elNum
for i in range(1, elNum+1):
    ResultArr[0][i-1] = i

Checking = True

lenResultArr = 1

while Checking:

    checkable = True

    for i in range(0, elNum):
        for ii in range(0, elNum): #
            if (CheckArr[i] == CheckArr[ii]) and not i == ii:
                checkable = False

    if checkable:
        status2 = [0]*lenResultArr
        for i1 in range(0, len(ResultArr)):
            print " "
            print "ResultArr[",i1,"] = ", ResultArr[i1]
            status1 = [0]*elNum
            for i2 in range(0, elNum):
                for i3 in range(0, elNum):
                    if ResultArr[i1][i2] == CheckArr[i3]:
                        status1[i2] = 1
                print "status1 = ", status1, "      ChechArr = ", CheckArr

            if sum(status1) == elNum:
                status2[i1] = 1
            print "status2[",str(i1),"] = ", status2[i1]

        if sum(status2) == 0:
            goodCheckArr = CheckArr
            ResultArr[lenResultArr] = goodCheckArr
            lenResultArr = lenResultArr + 1
            print "**** ResultArr = ", ResultArr
            print "sum(status2) = 0     len(ResultArr) = ", str(len(ResultArr)), "      lenResultArr = ", str(lenResultArr)
        else:
            print "sum(status2) > 0     len(ResultArr) = ", str(len(ResultArr)), "      lenResultArr = ", str(lenResultArr)

    print "************************************************************"
    print "***",ResultArr

    CheckArr[elNum-1] = CheckArr[elNum-1] + 1
    for i in range(elNum-1, -1, -1):
        if CheckArr[i] > elLimit:
            CheckArr[i-1] = CheckArr[i-1] + 1
            CheckArr[i] = 1
            Checking = False
        else:
            Checking = True

    print "************************************************************"
    print "***",ResultArr
```

I think y problem is in the last piece of code:

```
    print "************************************************************"
    print "***",ResultArr

    CheckArr[elNum-1] = CheckArr[elNum-1] + 1
    for i in range(elNum-1, -1, -1):
        if CheckArr[i] > elLimit:
            CheckArr[i-1] = CheckArr[i-1] + 1
            CheckArr[i] = 1
            Checking = False
        else:
            Checking = True

    print "************************************************************"
    print "***",ResultArr
```

The output looks like this:

```
************************************************************
*** {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [1, 2, 4]}
************************************************************
*** {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [1, 2, 5]}
```

**I have no idea why new elements of changeble checking arrey apears in results array.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply use the following code to get all the combinations of length 2.

```
import itertools
persons = [1, 2, 3, 4]

comb = itertools.combinations(persons, 2)

for i in comb:
    print i

(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! so simple... Thank you very much. Still, have you any idea why new elements of changeble checking arrey apeared in results array?